# Need help on a simple circuit LM317T

Tags: circuit-design

I want to make a Lm317 4.5a output circuit. So I want to know that- do I need any resistor on point 3 & 4? And which capacitor will be best for point 1 & 2. Pls help me.
[image]

Comment: See page 16 in the [TI datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) for LM317.

Comment: I don't have all components from datasheet. Pls help me what I asked for.

Comment: Lacking components, use one LM317 in the short shoulder (KCS) variety of TO-220 and clamp its bottom side to a big cooler looking like this: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/811Jg0bp8eL._SL1500_.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Here is the circuit you should be using from the LM317 data sheet! You'll notice your resistors at 3 and 4 are there to protect the individual supplies from slightly different outputs.

In this example they're using an OP Amp to set the adjust voltage but you could actually just set them all the same (with fixed resistors) assuming you don't want it variable.

In any case you'll need a nice big heatsink to get this much current out of the chips. Id suggest using a large metal plate if you've got nothing else.

Hope that helps!
[image]

Comment: Only the last lm317 getting hot. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the first circuit in [LM317 High Current Voltage Regulator](http://www.reuk.co.uk/wordpress/electric-circuit/lm317-high-current-voltage-regulator/)

Naturally TI prefers you to buy more TI circuits, but this solution is simpler and cheaper => better.